# Python: how to write a "main" function with optional arguments

Tags: python

I'm looking to create a python script which has two optional arguments, window and lake, which default to 5 and False, respectively. Window should be able to take any integer while lake should be able to take the values False and integers between 1-164 inclusive. This is the code I currently have:

```
import sys

def bla(window, lake):

    if isinstance(lake, bool) | isinstance(lake, int):
        if lake > 164:
            print("Please select a lake between IDs 1 and 164, else leave this argument blank.")
            sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print("Please select a lake between IDs 1 and 164, else leave this argument blank.")
        sys.exit(1)

    print(window * lake) #This is just a sample use of the function

def main(argv):
    if len(argv) == 1:
        bla(window = 5, lake = False)
    if len(argv) >= 2:
        window = sys.argv[1]
        if len(argv) == 2:
            bla(window, lake = False)
    if len(argv) == 3:
        lake = sys.argv[2]
        bla(window, lake)
    if len(argv) > 3:
        print("This function takes a maximum of two arguments.")
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Unfortunately my code doesn't seem to work; I end up with Python believing that the lake variable is over 164 regardless of what my input is. I'm also not happy with all my if statements in the main function; I imagine there to be a better way to deal with optional arguments. Any ideas? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: IMO the most elegant way is to use the `ArgumentParser` from the argparse module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Command line arguments are always passed as strings. If you want something else, you need to do the conversion yourself. Or even better, as Sven points out, use a library to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified the code in the `main()` method. You will need the convert the parameters to the correct type in your `bla()` method.

```
import sys

def bla(window, lake):
    if window is None:
        window = 5
    if lake is None:
        lake = False
    # Add logic here
    print(int(window))
    print(int(lake))


def main(params):
    NUM_PARAMS = 2 # Number of expected parameters
    if len(params) > NUM_PARAMS:
        print("This function takes a maximum of two arguments.")
        sys.exit(1)
    # Pad the list of parameters with `None` to meet the expected number
    while (len(params) < NUM_PARAMS):
        params.append(None)
    # Call `bla()`
    bla(*params)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # only pass parameters to main()
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

When receiving command line arguments, you should convert them to the appropiate type since they are initially strings.

So you can replace

```py
lake = sys.argv[2]
```

to

```py
lake = int(sys.argv[2])
```